# XPath: Check if parent sibling with value equals for-each value

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Currently I've got the following XML. In this Example I used 4 `fieldOptions`, but it goes up to 50-something.

```
<filterItem>
    <field name="incidentState" fieldLabel="Status" type="filterType" mandatory="false">
        <fieldOption><![CDATA[0]]></fieldOption>
        <fieldOption><![CDATA[1]]></fieldOption>
        <fieldOption><![CDATA[4]]></fieldOption>
        <init>
            <fieldOption value="0">Geen</fieldOption>
            <fieldOption value="2">Registratie</fieldOption>
            <fieldOption value="3">Analyse</fieldOption>
            <fieldOption value="4">Plannen</fieldOption>
            <init> </init>
        </init>
    </field>
</filterItem>
```

In this case I want the output to create 3 `li` elements. At first an `li` element containing the fieldLabel of the field node. The other `li` elements should be every `init/fieldOption` of which the `value` attribute equals a `../../fieldOption` text.
Since an example makes it clearer, this is the output I'd like:

```
<li>Status</li>
<li>Geen</li>
<li>Plannen</li>
```

I use the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="filterItem">
  <ul id="filter_{field/@name}">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="field/@fieldLabel"/>
    </li>
    <xsl:for-each select="field/init/fieldOption">
      <xsl:if test="../../fieldOption[. = @value]">
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </li>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

This doesn't work, and unfortunately I'm clueless about how I could get this to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `current()` in `<xsl:if test="../../fieldOption[. = current()/@value]">` to compare the outer context (`init/fieldOption`) with the context in the predicate.